# Blank page on 3dsecure landing from Cardinity Redirect

Tags: 3d-secure

I have a problem with my Cardinity integration.
Im trying to get 3dsecure to work. But when I land on 3dsecure, I get blank page.

The flow is as following:

Purchase Reqeust (My page) -> Cardinity handle -> Redirect back to my page, with custom form populated with data from cardinity (is mentioned below) -> Form Post to 3dsecure -> Blank page.

Form:

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ $url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="ThreeDForm" class="col-md-12">

<button type="submit" class="btn">Go to payment</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="{{ $data }}" />
          <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="https://custom.com/dashboard/{{ md5(Auth::user()->email) }}/3dsecure/callback" />
          <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="{{ $id }}" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alot of undefined variables, but my guess is that you are putting in `entype`, which isnt listed in their documentation. Try delete this, if you dont have a specific reason of using it.